# Is there a probability measure on $[0,1]$ with no subsets with measure $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I have a decidedly weird question.

Does there exist a probability measure $(\mu, \mathcal{F})$ on $[0,1]$ such that

1) $\mu(x) = 0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$

2) For every $r \in [0,1] \setminus \lbrace \frac{1}{2} \rbrace$, there exists $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(A) = r$, and

3) There is no $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(A) = \frac{1}{2}$?

The question comes about from a prelim problem in which the existence of a measure-$\frac{1}{2}$ set was assumed, and it made me wonder whether the assumption was for convenience or necessary.  Pigeonhole principle?  Ultrafilters?

Comment: Show function $\phi(t) := \mu([0,t])$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, it works (to show the non-existence of such a measure).  Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, your solution is actually incorrect.  The measurability of those sets isn't assumed.  Will $\phi$ still be continuous if we replace $\mu$ with $\mu^*$?

Comment: OK, if this is not assumed a Borel measure, then you will have to show it is a nonatomic measure then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29

Comment: So are you saying the original statement will be true if we assume that $\mu$ is non-atomic, or that the outer measure will be continuous if it's non-atomic?

Comment: My second hint is also no good ... 1) and 2) do not imply the measure is nonatomic.  So we have to go to... "Halmos showed that the range of a non-negative, finite measure is a closed subset of real numbers." see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160338/

Comment: @GEdgar maybe worth converting into an answer? That does appear to settle the OP's question (now, whether such a hammer is required to do so, I don't know, but at least it does the job).

Comment: Does the assumption that such  a measure does not exist for the 1/2-case  imply that this is not true in the   p-case,   p  in (0,1)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $\mathcal F$ is any $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, this is essentially the general case of:

> Halmos [1] showed that the range of a non-negative, finite measure is a closed subset of real numbers.

---

[1] Halmos, Paul R. *On the set of values of a finite measure.* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 53 (1947), no. 2, 138--141. 
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510408.